# JComponent disappear when resizing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Hi i am a beginner in java, here I have my program, however, when I try resizing the panel my text just disappears?
Moreover, how can i draw a thick green line under my text which will stay under the text even when resizing, I am very clueless?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class Groovy
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame= new JFrame("Shearing Word Demo");

                frame.setResizable(true);
                frame.setSize(new Dimension(500,250));
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                Toolkit it=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
                Dimension d=it.getScreenSize();
                int w=frame.getWidth(), h=frame.getHeight();
                frame.setLocation(d.width/2-w/2, d.height/2-h/2);
                frame.add(new JComponent(){
                    @Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D) g;
                        g2.setColor(Color.magenta);
                        g2.setFont(new Font("Comic Sans MS",Font.BOLD,44));
                        g2.drawString("Feeling Groovy!", 110,125 );
                    }
                });
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: *when I try resizing the panel my text just disappears?* - not sure what you mean. You can resize the frame, which causes the panel to resize, but the text is still repainted. So I'm not sure what your problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can i draw a thick green line under my text which will stay under the text even when resizing, I

If you do custom painting then the basic steps you need to follow would be something like:

1. get the FontMetrics of the Graphics object using the getFonTMetrics() method
2. get the rectangle of text using the getStringBounds(...) method
3. use the setStroke(...) method of the Graphics2D object to set the thickness of the line to paint
4. use the drawLine(...) method Graphics2D object to paint the line based on the location of the text and the information of the Rectangle from the string bounds

An easier solution for displaying text is to use a `JLabel`. Then you can set the Border of the label. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information.

Note when doing custom painting with a JComponent you are also responsible for clearing the background of the component. So the first painting in the method should be:

```
g2.setColor( getBackground() );
g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Most people use a JPanel for custom painting then you can just use:

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

to make sure the background is cleared.